# Rubymine / Intellij Ruby plugin: how to custom test format

Tags: intellij-idea, rspec, rubymine

When running an individual test by right clicking on it and running, the command always append a teamcity formatter for rspec.

This formatter setting is not configurable in Edit Configurations. Is there any way to remove the default formatter in the IDE? I want the convenient way to trigger a test but also to get rid of the default formatter.

Comment: At the moment  there's no way to remove it. Could you please specify why you'd like to use another formatter?

Comment: It just doesn't make sense to have the formatter as teamcity which has nothing to do with my local development